# clock_t does not work on Linux?

Tags: c++

This is what I have been using in WIndows:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main( void )
{
    using namespace std;

    clock_t lastT;
    lastT = clock();

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

In Linux I get the error:

```
'clock_t' was not declared in this scope
```

Is there some other data type for this in Linux?

I am compiling it in Anjuta IDE by clicking Run.

Comment: How are you compiling this? Because I used `g++ -o clock clock.cpp` where clock.cpp is exactly your code and it compiles fine. g++ v 4.5.1

Comment: Works for me (Ubuntu 10.10 amd64)

Comment: I compile it in IDE by clicking Run.

Comment: Since you are on Linux. It is a fair bet the compiler is GCC. Your IDE is probably uisng the default compiler (though it may be using its own). Try finding the version of GCC as a starting point. Open terminal window and type `gcc --version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I have solved it by using:

```
int lastT;
```

instead. The rest works the same way.

Answer (score 4):

Your IDE/compiler is not compliant.  The C++ standard requires the `<ctime>` header to be identical to the C99 header `<time.h>`, except that symbols are placed in the `std` namespace (C++03, §17.4.1.2/4).  C99 §7.23.1/3 requires `<time.h>` to declare `clock_t` to be an arithmetic type capable of representing time.

So, if your implementation does not declare `clock_t`, it is not compliant with the C++ standard.

Comment: That would mean gcc is not compliant.

Answer (score 2):

I copy/paste/compile and I don't get any issue on linux.

```
> uname -a
Linux xxxhappy 2.6.16.46-0.12-bigsmp #1 SMP Thu May 17 14:00:09 UTC 2007 i686
i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

See `man 3 clock` for more info.

If your file is named `main.cpp` you can compile it from command line:

```
g++ -o main.o -c -g -Wall main.cpp
g++ -o app main.o
```

or in one step:

```
g++ -o app main.cpp
```

Your executable will be named `app`, you can name it whatever you want.